# How can I export a vpn configuration in windows and import it in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, windows, vpn, configuration

In my workplace there is a vpn to connect to the internet,the vpn is for windows(yeah,no joke)but when I enter the configuration of vpn in windows and ubuntu the both are a hell diferent .Somebody can help me?(sorry for bad english)
The vpn Config is
enable extensions LCP

CHAP
MS-CHAP v2

and the vpn is pptp

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of Ubuntu that you're using so that we might better help in troubleshooting your issue.

Comment: And please provide what protocol of VPN (PPTP, OpenVPN, L2TP/IPsec,  SSTP) you have on MS Windows.

Comment: is a pptp vpn,the ubuntu version is 16.02 LTS(I think)